# Problem in passing a method to a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I create a new timer in main function :

```
int main(){
Timer t1(5);
return 0;
 }
```

And here is my constructor

```
Timer::Timer(int seconds, int minutes, int hours) : myID(freeID++) {
  _currentTime = Time::getDefault();
  _currentDate = Date::getDefault();
  int totalWaitSeconds = seconds + minutes * 60 + hours * 60 * 60;
 std::thread newThread(&Timer::startTimer,this, totalWaitSeconds);
}

void Timer::startTimer(int start) {
  while (start > 0) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    --start;
  }
  cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
       << "            !!!DING DING DING!!!"
       << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" 
       << "Timer with ID[" << this->myID << "], went off"
       << endl;

}
```

I can't get how I can pass the method to thread with a value that I need. Either I get runtime error (abort), or it says that no matching overloaded for std::invoke, when I try to do it like this:

```
 std::thread newThread(&Timer::startTimer, totalWaitSeconds);
```

EDIT:
It works now, but still, I get a crash at the start. So it crashes, but still continues to do its job perfectly. I have no idea how to fix it

non-important .h file

```
Timer(int seconds = 0, int minutes=0, int hours=0);
```

new edit, like this?:

```
class Timer {
private:
  std::thread timerThread;
}
```

```
Timer::Timer(int seconds, int minutes, int hours) : myID(freeID++) {
  _currentTime = Time::getDefault();
  _currentDate = Date::getDefault();
  int totalWaitSeconds = seconds + minutes * 60 + hours * 60 * 60;
  timerThread = thread(&Timer::startTimer,this, totalWaitSeconds);

}

Timer::~Timer() {
    timerThread.join();
}
```

Comment: `Timer t1(5)` will construct a `Timer` object using the one parameter constructor that takes an int, which you have not shown us.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it's the same constructor, in .h file I have ``` Timer(int seconds = 0, int minutes=0, int hours=0); ```

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm this is not related to problem

Comment: [Edit] the question to include all relevant details (a [mre]).  Ideally enough so that we can copy your code, compile it locally, and reproduce the error (and no more than that).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that is not related to problem at all. That's why I didn't include it in my snippet, but ok.

Comment: consider packaging the thread and the functions inside the same (class instance).  The timer is easier to access when the thread is also running in the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either `join()` or `detach()` thread object before destroying it. Otherwise the [`thread` destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) will call `std::terminate`.

In your case, the well-behaved solution will be to store the `std::thread` inside `Timer` object and call `join()` in destructor. This is because you should be thinking about threads as resources and employ RAII to manage them.

```
Timer::~Timer() {
    if (timerThread.joinable())
        timerThread.join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it, it worked, and then I got your answer :D Thank you anyway <3

Comment: newThread.join(); after creating the thread fixed the problem

Comment: @LordNani, I've added a suggestion about managing threads. Note that if you just `join()` in constructor, then your constructor will block until the timer elapses which might not necessarily be what you actually want, otherwise you could've just called `std::this_thread::sleep_for` from the main thread.

Comment: after destructor, it crashes

Comment: @LordNani, you should check `joinable()` before calling `join()`.

Comment: @r3mux_n0x      adding  if(timerThread.joinable())
  timerThread.join();   didn't fix it

Comment: Because right after creating the t1 object, the main thread ends the int main, and automatically calls timer destructor

Comment: @LordNani, yes, but because you're calling `join()` in destructor, it will actually wait until timer's thread is finished. I'm not sure why is it still crashing, try debugging to see where exactly that crash is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass a member function directly to std::thread.  std::thread expects a free function, a static member function, or a lambda.

Using a lambda is easiest and should work for you.

```
std::thread newThread([this, totalWaitSeconds]() { startTimer(totalWaitSeconds); });
```

Comment: don't want to argue, but it works without lambdas, no idea why

Comment: Possibly an override.  Can't memorize them all.  As r3mus n0x points below, don't forget to call std::thread::join() or more likely detach() , in your case, after the constructor.  Or your app will crash.

Comment: Yeah, that was part of a problem, I fixed it already. Thanks for lambda, I will try to implement it